# C# how to modify the linkedlist node property?

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a linkedlist class like follows:

```
public class DbNode<T>
{

    private T _data;
    private DbNode<T> _prev;
    private DbNode<T> _next;

    public T Data
    {
        get { return this._data; }
        set { this._data = value; }
    }

    public DbNode<T> Prev
    {
        get { return this._prev; }
        set { this._prev = value; }
    }

    public DbNode<T> Next
    {
        get { return this._next; }
        set { this._next = value; }
    }

    public DbNode(T data, DbNode<T> prev, DbNode<T> next)
    {
        this._data = data;
        this._prev = prev;
        this._next = next;
    }

    public DbNode(T data, DbNode<T> prev)
    {
        this._data = data;
        this._prev = prev;
        this._next = null;
    }


    public DbNode(DbNode<T> next)
    {
        this._data = default(T);
        this._next = next;
        this._prev = null;
    }

    public DbNode(T data)
    {
        this._data = data;
        this._prev = null;
        this._next = null;
    }

    public DbNode()
    {
        this._data = default(T);
        this._prev = null;
        this._next = null;
    }
}

public class DbLinkedList<T>
{

    private DbNode<T> _head;

    public DbNode<T> Head
    {
        get { return this._head; }
        set { this._head = value; }
    }

    public DbLinkedList()
    {
        Head = null;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetItemAt(index);
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return Head == null;
    }

    public T GetItemAt(int i)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The double linked list is empty.");
            return default(T);
        }

        DbNode<T> p = new DbNode<T>();
        p = Head;

        if (0 == i)
        {
            return p.Data;
        }

        int j = 0;
        while (p.Next != null && j < i)
        {
            j++;
            p = p.Next;
        }

        if (j == i)
        {
            return p.Data;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The node dose not exist.");
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        DbNode<T> p = Head;
        int length = 0;
        while (p != null)
        {
            length++;
            p = p.Next;
        }
        return length;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.Head = null;
    }

    public void AddAfter(T item, int i)
    {
        if (IsEmpty() || i < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The double linked list is empty or the position is uncorrect.");
            return;
        }

        if (0 == i) 
        {
            DbNode<T> newNode = new DbNode<T>(item);
            newNode.Next = Head.Next;
            Head.Next.Prev = newNode;
            Head.Next = newNode;
            newNode.Prev = Head;
            return;
        }

        DbNode<T> p = Head;
        int j = 0;

        while (p != null && j < i)
        {
            p = p.Next;
            j++;
        }

        if (j == i)
        {
            DbNode<T> newNode = new DbNode<T>(item);
            newNode.Next = p.Next;
            if (p.Next != null)
            {
                p.Next.Prev = newNode;
            }
            newNode.Prev = p;
            p.Next = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The position is uncorrect.");
        }

    }

    public void AddBefore(T item, int i)
    {
        if (IsEmpty() || i < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The double linked list is empty or the position is uncorrect.");
            return;
        }

        if (0 == i) 
        {
            DbNode<T> newNode = new DbNode<T>(item);
            newNode.Next = Head; 
            Head.Prev = newNode;
            Head = newNode; 
            return;
        }

        DbNode<T> n = Head;
        DbNode<T> d = new DbNode<T>();
        int j = 0;

        while (n.Next != null && j < i)
        {
            d = n; 
            n = n.Next;
            j++;
        }

        if (n.Next == null)
        {
            DbNode<T> newNode = new DbNode<T>(item);
            n.Next = newNode;
            newNode.Prev = n;
            newNode.Next = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (j == i)
            {
                DbNode<T> newNode = new DbNode<T>(item);
                d.Next = newNode;
                newNode.Prev = d;
                newNode.Next = n;
                n.Prev = newNode;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddLast(T item)
    {
        DbNode<T> newNode = new DbNode<T>(item);
        DbNode<T> p = new DbNode<T>();

        if (Head == null)
        {
            Head = newNode;
            return;
        }
        p = Head; 
        while (p.Next != null)
        {
            p = p.Next;
        }
        p.Next = newNode;
        newNode.Prev = p;
    }

    public T RemoveAt(int i)
    {
        if (IsEmpty() || i < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The double linked list is empty or the position is uncorrect.");
            return default(T);
        }

        DbNode<T> q = new DbNode<T>();
        if (0 == i)
        {
            q = Head;
            Head = Head.Next;
            Head.Prev = null;
            return q.Data;
        }

        DbNode<T> p = Head;
        int j = 0;

        while (p.Next != null && j < i)
        {
            j++;
            q = p;
            p = p.Next;
        }

        if (i == j)
        {
            p.Next.Prev = q;
            q.Next = p.Next;
            return p.Data;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The position is uncorrect.");
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T value)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The list is empty.");
            return -1;
        }

        DbNode<T> p = new DbNode<T>();
        p = Head;
        int i = 0;
        while (p.Next != null && !p.Data.Equals(value))
        {
            p = p.Next;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void Reverse()
    {
        DbLinkedList<T> tmpList = new DbLinkedList<T>();
        DbNode<T> p = this.Head;
        tmpList.Head = new DbNode<T>(p.Data);
        p = p.Next;

        while (p != null)
        {
            tmpList.AddBefore(p.Data, 0);
            p = p.Next;
        }

        this.Head = tmpList.Head;
        tmpList = null;
    }

    public string ReverseByPrev()
    {
        DbNode<T> tail = GetNodeAt(Count() - 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(tail.Data.ToString() + ",");
        while (tail.Prev != null)
        {
            sb.Append(tail.Prev.Data + ",");
            tail = tail.Prev;
        }
        return sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
    }

    private DbNode<T> GetNodeAt(int i)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The list is empty.");
            return null;
        }

        DbNode<T> p = new DbNode<T>();
        p = this.Head;

        if (0 == i)
        {
            return p;
        }

        int j = 0;
        while (p.Next != null && j < i)
        {
            j++;
            p = p.Next;
        }
        if (j == i)
        {
            return p;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The node does not exist.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public T Fisrt()
    {
        return this.GetItemAt(0);
    }

    public T Last()
    {
        return this.GetItemAt(this.Count() - 1);
    }

}
```

And I alse have a class as `Product` which contains properties:`ProductID` and `ProductValue`:

```
public class Product
{

    private byte _productID;
    public byte ProductID
    {
        get { return _productID; }
        set
        {
            _productID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductID");
        }
    }

    private UInt16 _productValue;
    public UInt16 ProductValue
    {
        get { return _productValue; }
        set
        {
            _productValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductValue");
        }
    }
}
```

I have another listbox to which I want to add the `Product` when I click the TreeView:

```
MyLinkList<Product> myLinkList = new MyLinkList<Product>();
private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var item = this.TreeView.SelectedItem as Product;
     listbox.Items.Add(item);
     myLinkList.Append(item);
}
```

Now the problem is I want to modify the item's property selected to add based on the former one. For example: if the former one's `ProductID` is `1`, then this `SelectedItem.ProductValue = FormerItem.ProductValue + 1`, how I suppose to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You need a doubly linked list. Right now you only track next but not previous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What should I do after I tracked the doubly linked list?

Comment: Actually before you append the item to the link, the item which is the last item in the link is the former item so you can get it using `GetElem` method. If append returned a node then you would use that and get the previous item in a doubly link.